# $\LaTeX$ compilation on Closing dialog

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

In voting a question to be closed it is absolutely imperative to be able and inspect the details of the proposed duplicate and the original question.

At times it is very inconvenient to open a new window or tab for the proposed duplicate (a question another user has pointed as a possible for duplication). The dialog does not compile $\LaTeX$ which on this site severely impairs the judgment to whether or not the questions are identical.

(Once more I find myself asking for the system to render code in less usual places...)

Comment: Closing questions doesn't happen terribly often and it only takes a few more clicks to open in a new tab, inspect, then close and either vote or X out of the dialog box, so I disagree it is "very inconvenient." We probably waste more time refreshing the main page than anything this trivial...

Comment: @anon: Personally I spend more time refreshing the main page then I do eating. I am lazy, and a system that strives to be complete, to some extent, needs to be complete. Just as much as I want $\LaTeX$ compiled on suggested edits review, I want it compiled on closing dialogs and in tag wiki excerpts.